# Do a SET operation over a Permutation result

Tags: r

This question should be very easy to solve but it seems to be quite hard to find an answer online.

I have created a permutation list out of the following command:

```
perms_vars <- permutations(n = 30, r = 4, v = names(vars))
```

Where `vars` is a list of variables. For example: `vars = c("V1", "V2", ..., "V30")`

From that I will get all the permutations of size 4 from my list of variables.
The problem is I don't need the following:

```
(V1, V2, V3, V4),
(V1, V2, V4, V3), 
...
```

So I've tried to find a way to make a SET operation on `perms_vars`  which will solve my problem and get me that Unique combination of 4 variables.

To sum up, I don't care about the order of the variables in the rows created in perms_vars. But I do care to have all the combination of Variables in that Matrix (Combinations by row).

Lets simplify what I want by considering the following scenario:

`names(vars)` will get me `"V1", "V2", "V3"`

```
perms_vars <- permutations(n = 3, r = 2, v = names(vars)).
```

From that I will get:

```
V1, V2
V1, V3
V2, V1
V2, V3
V3, V1
V3, V2
```

What I want is only:

```
V1, V2
V1, V3
V2, V3
```

Any ideas? Quick resolve for that simple problem?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. `vars` is not a `list` but a `vector`(it's a `list` in python but `vector` in R). Please specify the expected output.

Comment: I've added a full example specify what I want.

Comment: For that you need `combn()`. Also just curious which package has that 'permutations()` function?

Comment: Knew it is simple as that. Thanks mate. It is from gtools

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use

```
t(combn(x = names(vars), m = 4))
```

where x is your vector and m is the length of the combination.

Comment: I think it's courtesy to ask the commenter who helped if they'd like to post as an answer

Comment: Sorry, I thought he didn't want to so I did it myself. I'll be glad to get his answer for an answer